# Writing to a USB device via WinUsb

Tags: c++, winusb

**LAST UPDATE :**

Now I have a string compatible with my device (it had to be in a specific format of non-printable bytes), but an infinite loop. The program never exits WinUsb_WritePipe.

**ORIGINAL TROUBLE :**

After initializing all my WinUsb interface (as precised in this well done MSDN tutorial : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff540174(v=vs.85).aspx)

I get everything well setup and sending true without error, except for the last step.

```
PWINUSB_INTERFACE_HANDLE piUsbHandle = new WINUSB_INTERFACE_HANDLE();
USB_INTERFACE_DESCRIPTOR *eUsbInterfaceDescriptor = new USB_INTERFACE_DESCRIPTOR();

WinUsb_Initialize(sfhDeviceHandle, piUsbHandle) //true

devInfo->winUsbHandle = *piUsbHandle;

WinUsb_QueryInterfaceSettings(*piUsbHandle, 1, eUsbInterfaceDescriptor) //true

for (int i= 0; i <= eUsbInterfaceDescriptor->bNumEndpoints - 1; i++)
{
        if (!WinUsb_QueryPipe((WINUSB_INTERFACE_HANDLE)devInfo->winUsbHandle, 1, (unsigned char)i, &eWinUsbPipeInformation))
        {
            return NULL;
        }
        if (((eWinUsbPipeInformation.PipeType == UsbdPipeTypeBulk)
             & this->isUsbEndPointDirectionIn(eWinUsbPipeInformation.PipeId)))
        {
            UtilityFunctions::displayTrace("initializeDevice : devInfo->bulkInPipe set");
            std::cout << "New In Pipe = " <<  (int)eWinUsbPipeInformation.PipeId << std::endl;
            devInfo->bulkInPipe = eWinUsbPipeInformation.PipeId;
        }
        else if (((eWinUsbPipeInformation.PipeType == UsbdPipeTypeBulk)
                  & this->isUsbEndpointDirectionOut(eWinUsbPipeInformation.PipeId)))
        {
            UtilityFunctions::displayTrace("initializeDevice : devInfo->bulkOutPipe set");
            std::cout << "New Out Pipe = " <<  (int)eWinUsbPipeInformation.PipeId << std::endl;
            devInfo->bulkOutPipe = eWinUsbPipeInformation.PipeId;
        }
        else if (((eWinUsbPipeInformation.PipeType == UsbdPipeTypeInterrupt)
                  & this->isUsbEndPointDirectionIn(eWinUsbPipeInformation.PipeId)))
        {
            UtilityFunctions::displayTrace("initializeDevice : devInfo->InterruptInPipe set");
            devInfo->interruptInPipe = eWinUsbPipeInformation.PipeId;
        }
        else if (((eWinUsbPipeInformation.PipeType == UsbdPipeTypeInterrupt)
                  & this->isUsbEndpointDirectionOut(eWinUsbPipeInformation.PipeId)))
        {
            UtilityFunctions::displayTrace("initializeDevice : devInfo->InterruptOutPipe set");
            devInfo->interruptOutPipe = eWinUsbPipeInformation.PipeId;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "No settings for " << i << std::endl;
            continue;
        }
}
```

(devInfo is a custom object containing a `WINUSB_INTERFACE_HANDLE` and the `PipeId` needed to write on the device)

It prints

```
initializeDevice : bNumEndpoints => 6
initializeDevice : devInfo->bulkOutPipe set
New Out Pipe = 1
initializeDevice : devInfo->bulkInPipe set
New In Pipe = 129
initializeDevice : devInfo->bulkOutPipe set
New Out Pipe = 2
initializeDevice : devInfo->bulkOutPipe set
New Out Pipe = 4
initializeDevice : devInfo->bulkInPipe set
New In Pipe = 134
initializeDevice : devInfo->bulkInPipe set
New In Pipe = 136
```

But for the last step, which is writing :

```
UCHAR ucBuffer[] = "Hello world";
ULONG uiBytesToWrite = 11;
ULONG ulBytesWritten = 0;

if (devInfo->winUsbHandle == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
    return;
}


WinUsb_WritePipe(devInfo->winUsbHandle, devInfo->bulkOutPipe, ucBuffer, uiBytesToWrite, &ulBytesWritten, 0);//ERROR 87 : INVALID PARAMETER
```

I've tried with every PipeId possible (from 0 to 255 since it's on one byte) but still gets the same error.
[The WinUsb_WritePipe MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff540322(v=vs.85).aspx) doesn't say anything about error 87.

Comment: Documentation says that "The buffer length must be a multiple of the maximum endpoint packet size." Maybe that's it?

Comment: It might be...Although that sounds like klingon to me. I'll take a look at what is meant by endpoint packet size. I think it's about USB_ENDPOINT_DESCRIPTOR

Comment: @bartop But in the tutorial they just say that the buffer length is a strlen of the UCHAR * passed as a message, they contradict themselves between each documents

Comment: "length is a strlen of the UCHAR *" - that's perfectly compatible with the fact that the buffer size is restricted to multiple of packet size. Perhaps you have to stuff your "Helo world" with additional chars to make the size of the buffer right

Comment: @bartop I'll try that

Comment: @bartop No change whatever the size of the buffer...