# WinUsb_WritePipe goes into an infinite loop

Tags: c++, infinite-loop, winusb

I'm using the [WinUsb_WritePipe function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff540322(v=vs.85).aspx) to write data on a USB Device.

The only trouble is that the function does an infinite loop.

```
//bulkOutPipe is a pipeId set precedently
//ucBuffer is an unsigned char array
//uiBytesToWrite corresponds to the size of the array
//ulBytesWritten is a unsigned long to stock the bytes written

std::cout << "Started writing" << std::endl;

WinUsb_WritePipe(devInfo->winUsbHandle, devInfo->bulkOutPipe, ucBuffer, uiBytesToWrite, &ulBytesWritten, 0);

//never gets here
```

This function [used to return false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44158204/writing-to-a-usb-device-via-winusb) but now it doesn't return anything.

Comment: Have you looked at the traffic with a USB protocol analyzer like the Total Phase Beagle?  Maybe the device is not ACKing the data so WinUSB must keep retrying forever.  Did you try setting a timeout?  Did you try rebooting your computer and power cycling the device?

Comment: I tried a reboot, and according to the documentation the WinUsb_WritePipe has a default timeout. But I'll try to set a custom one.

I don't know if the Total Phase Beagle will work as the USB is made by the company I work for.

Comment: @DavidGrayson Well if I set the timeout...It hits the timeout.

Comment: OK, so that solves the infinite loop issue.  Your device probably is not ACKing the transfer and it will be not possible to figure out that issue with the information given.

Comment: @DavidGrayson I will try to see with the hardware engineers then, thanks

Comment: The Total Phase Beagle device doesn't know or care who makes the device it is analyzing, of course.  It is a general purpose tool and it is very useful for debugging USB communication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid an infinite loop, I would recommend always setting a timeout for I/O operations like this. You can use the [WinUSB Functions for Pipe Policy Modification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/usbcon/winusb-functions-for-pipe-policy-modification).